# Extjs - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of null

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4.2, init

I am trying to create a simple form using Extjs scripting. I am unable to see the output due to this error on Chrome console:-

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of null ext-all.js:21**
Ext.cmd.derive.create ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.constructPlugin ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.constructPlugins ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent ext-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent ext-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent ext-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent ext-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent ext-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.constructor ext-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.constructor ext-all.js:21
A ext-all.js:21
Ext.apply.widget ext-all.js:21
Ext.application.launch app1.js:30
Ext.cmd.derive.onBeforeLaunch ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.constructor ext-all.js:21
j ext-all.js:21
(anonymous function) ext-all.js:21
(anonymous function) ext-all.js:21
fire ext-all.js:21
Ext.apply.readyEvent.j.fire ext-all.js:21
Ext.apply.fireReadyEvent ext-all.js:21
(anonymous function)
```

If I import **ext-all-debug.js** or **ext-debug.js** the error goes away but two other error gets displayed on the console. Please find the errors:-

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null ext-all-debug.js:19552**
(anonymous function) ext-all-debug.js:19552
classReady ext-all-debug.js:5401
Ext.ClassManager.onCreated ext-all-debug.js:5016
Ext.ClassManager.createOverride ext-all-debug.js:5409
Ext.apply.define ext-all-debug.js:5727
(anonymous function) ext-all-debug.js:18865
**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addCls' ext-all.js:21**
d ext-all.js:21
(anonymous function) ext-all.js:21
fire ext-all.js:21
Ext.apply.readyEvent.j.fire ext-all.js:21
Ext.apply.fireReadyEvent ext-all.js:21
(anonymous function)
```

Please find my Extjs code:-

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});
//Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'extjs/src/ux');

Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.layout.container.Column',
    'Ext.tab.Panel',
    //'*',
    'Ext.ux.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

    var bd = Ext.getBody();

    /*
     * ================  Simple form  =======================
     */
    bd.createChild({tag: 'h2', html: 'Form 1 - Very Simple'});
    var required = '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>';
    var simple = Ext.widget({
        xtype: 'form',
        layout: 'form',
        collapsible: true,
        id: 'simpleForm',
        //url: 'save-form.php',
        frame: true,
        title: 'Simple Form',
        bodyPadding: '5 5 0',
        width: 350,
        fieldDefaults: {
            msgTarget: 'side',
            labelWidth: 75
        },
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'datatip'
        },
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            afterLabelTextTpl: required,
            name: 'first',
            allowBlank: false,
            qtip: 'Enter your first name'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            afterLabelTextTpl: required,
            name: 'last',
            allowBlank: false,
            qtip: 'Enter your last name'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Company',
            name: 'company',
            tooltip: "Enter your employer's name"
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Email',
            afterLabelTextTpl: required,
            name: 'email',
            allowBlank: false,
            vtype:'email',
            tooltip: 'Enter your email address'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'DOB',
            name: 'dob',
            xtype: 'datefield',
            tooltip: 'Enter your date of birth'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Age',
            name: 'age',
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 100,
            tooltip: 'Enter your age'
        }, {
            xtype: 'timefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Time',
            name: 'time',
            minValue: '8:00am',
            maxValue: '6:00pm',
            tooltip: 'Enter a time',
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'datatip',
                tpl: 'Select time {date:date("G:i")}'
            }
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Save',
            handler: function() {
                this.up('form').getForm().isValid();
            }
        },{
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: function() {
                this.up('form').getForm().reset();
            }
        }]
    });
 simple.render(document.body);

 });
```

Comment: Since the trace seems to indicate it's an issue with instantiating the plugin, I'd check to make sure that the plugin is available in your app via it's ptype. For example, since you have the Loader.setPath(...) commented out, it's likely that the app can't resolve the path for the plugin you're trying to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...but even if I comment it out its still giving me the error. Plz find the error:-                        Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of null ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.create ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.constructPlugin ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.constructPlugins ext-all.js:21
Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent ext-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent ext-all.js:21
.....Plz help

Comment: By the way I have downladed Extjs framework Extjs -4.2.1 -GPL....just in case if there is an issue with it.

Comment: Is that path correct for the ux folder? It is definitely an issue with the plugins (I tested your code, and got the same error). Once you get the path to the ux folder properly mapped, it should work fine.

Comment: I would comment most of the code and just show a simple panel with a tittle just to be sure that I'm loading correctly the libraries ... If it loads correctly I would continue to uncomment the code until I realize what is breaking ... best regards

Comment: Thanks for the help.I imported Ext.ux.* and started working with simple panel. The issue also seemed to arise from improper tooltip syntax. Fox tooltip, I have changed the syntax to inputAttrTpl: " data-qtip='Enter your age!' ". The code is working fine now. Thanks once again.